# Apache just won't redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, .htaccess, passenger

I'm running Rails, Phusion-Passenger.

I have tried anything I have found on stack overflow, but maybe the sources are outdated or something.
My ssl is working and all. I just cant get it to redirect http to https. I get the **Bad Request 400** error, saying that I'm trying to access https site with plain http.

Here is the config of one of my sites.

```
<VirtualHost *:4000>
    ServerName beast.xxxxx.com

    # Tell Apache and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    DocumentRoot /var/www/cava/public

    PassengerRuby /home/tasos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@cava/wrappers/ruby

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

  SSLEngine On
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/2_beast.xxxxx.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/xxxxx_nopass.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/1_root_bundle.crt    



    # Relax Apache security settings
    <Directory /var/www/cava/public>
      Allow from all
      #Options -MultiViews
      # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
      #Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Rewrite is enabled, I'm sure of it.
Althouth I tried multiple codes already, can you suggest me your running code for the Rewrite function?

Do need to modify my .htaccess file or something like that? I have seen it written in many places, but I also read that that this file shouldn't be modified anymore.

I would like to hear any suggestions.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This is an "internal-only" rewrite, and the new URL is never shown to the client, because you didn't specify it should be a client-side redirection.

Try

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
                                                    ^^^^^^^
```

instead. the `[R...]` tells mod_rewrite to send the new url to the client as a formal http redirect.

Comment: Also, wouldn't it better to use `{SERVER_NAME}` instead of `{HTTP_HOST}` ??

Comment: no. servername is set in apache, and can be totally different. e.g. if you're using a hosting co, it could be something like `foo.bar.baz.hostingco.com`, and not `www.yoursite.com`. and this is especially true of an apache that hosts multiple domains.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you for explaining that @Marc B :) I appreciate you clearing that up.

Comment: @MarcB It does not work actually. Where else should I look for the problem? I have the server name same on both websites should I change it?